# How do I group multiple functions within one class in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, class, grouping

My JavaScript class module file contains multiple functions of various categories, such as file-operation related ones and string-processing related ones.

```
class App {
  static fileFunc1() {
    ...
  }

  static fileFunc2() {
    ...
  }

  static strFunc1() {
    ...
  }

  static strFunc2() {
    ...
  }
}
```

I wanted to categorize these functions within **ONE FILE** so that they can be called as a chained string as follows.

```
App.file.fileFunc1();
App.str.strFunc2();
```

After some trials and errors, I found the solution by myself as described below.

```
class App {
  /**
   * Group of file-operation related functions
   */
  static file {
    fileFunc1: () => {
      ...
    },

    fileFunc2: () => {
      ...
    }
  };

  /**
   * Group of string-processing related functions
   */
  static str {
    strFunc1: () => {
      ...
    },

    strFunc2: () => {
      ...
    }
  };
}
```

Is this the recommended way to achieve my needs?
Or are there any other recommended solutions or smart ideas?

#### [Additional remarks]

There is one thing I have to mention that **I don't want to divide those functions into multiple files** because there are already many generic module files and increasing the number of files is not welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A class with only static methods doesn't make much sense as a class - the primary benefit of a class is the ability to tie together *persistent data* with *methods* that operate on that data. If you never instantiate the class, consider whether a plain object would be more appropriate.

```
const App = {
  file: {
    fileFunc1: () => {
      // ...
    },
    fileFunc2: () => {
      // ...
    }
  },

  str: {
    strFunc1: () => {
      // ...
    },
    strFunc2: () => {
      // ...
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I understand that a plain object should be used when the class has only static methods. How about the class with both static  methods and dynamic methods?

Comment: If you mean methods that would be called on *instances* of the class - and those instances have non-method data properties on them as well - then having a class for such a situation would make perfect sense. (If the potential class only has methods but no data on the instance, a class probably isn't the right approach.)

Comment: Thanks again. I will use classes or objects depending on whether dynamic methods are needed or not.